# Como adicionar MouseClicked em um JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, eventos-do-mouse

Estou criando um programa com regras MVC em Java e gostaria de saber como crio um Evento num `JLabel` para quando eu clicar nele com o mouse.

Por exemplo, para os botões eu faço assim:

Classe View:

```
void addLogarListener(ActionListener cal) {
        btnLogar.addActionListener(cal);
    }
```

Classe Controller:

```
view.addLogarListener(new LogarListener());
//===================================
class LogarListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
             //Comandos
        }
    }
```

Comment: swing? Se for ele já trabalha com esse conceito. Eu particulamente acho bobeira ficar dando voltas pra criar algo que o proprio java ja faz pra facilitar nossa vida.

Comment: Mas em MVC não seria feito de uma forma diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a intenção é apenas efetuar alguma ação quando o mouse for clicado, basta sobrescrever o método `mouseClicked` conforme abaixo:

```
seuLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //aqui as operações quando o label for clicado
            }
        });
```

Ou se preferir fazer com uma classe a parte, como demonstrou no código, basta fazer assim:

```
//no seu label, você adicionar um mouselistener e passa uma instancia
//nova da classe personalizada
seuLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseEventos());
```

E criar outra classe estendendo [**`MouseAdapter`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)(pode ser implementando `MouseListener` tambem, mas vai obrigar a implementar todos os métodos de eventos de mouse):

```
class MouseEventos extends MouseAdapter{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mouseClicked(e);
    }
}
```